# Node & Gulp for SASS - Stack level too deep

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

Trying to use Gulp to compile my SASS into .css files
Used to use compass, and wanted to switch to Gulp instead.  This mixin below was not created by me but is being used.  One of the files for the header do use the mixin bp (does a breakpoint)

Also these issues sometimes happen and sometimes do not when running the sass compilation from Gulp.  Not always same exact spot reproduced.  I also removed css files, and recompiled with this error.  The css were still there and seemed to work.  What do I do?  Thoughts?

> Error in plugin 'sass'
>
> Message:
>      afa/scss/layout/_header-search.scss
>
> SystemStackError: stack level too deep
>
> ```
>               on line 41 of afa/scss/layout/_header-search.scss
> ```
>
> ---> @include bp(min-width, $bp-medium + 1) {
>          ---------^

Below is the Mixin from the file itself

```
// =============================================
// Mixin - Breakpoint
// =============================================

$mq-support: true !default;
$mq-fixed-value: 1024px !default;

@mixin bp($feature, $value) {
    // Set global device param
    $media: only screen;

    // Media queries supported
    @if $mq-support == true {

        @media #{$media} and ($feature: $value) {
            @content;
        }

        // Media queries not supported
    } @else {

        @if $feature == 'min-width' {
            @if $value <= $mq-fixed-value {
                @content;
            }
        } @else if $feature == 'max-width' {
            @if $value >= $mq-fixed-value {
                @content;
            }
        }

    }
}

/*
// ----------------------------------------------
// Usage example:
// For IE set $mq-support to false.
// Set the fixed value.
// Then use mixins to test whether styles should be applied.
// ----------------------------------------------

$mq-support: false;
$mq-fixed-value: 1024;

// Renders at fixed value
@include bp (min-width, 300px) { 
    div { color:#000; }
}

// Doesn't render without MQ support
@include bp (min-width, 1200px) { 
    div { color:#FFF; }
}

// Doesn't render without MQ support
@include bp (max-width, 300px) { 
    div { color:#444; }
}

// Renders at fixed value
@include bp (max-width, 1200px) { 
    div { color:#888; }
}

// ----------------------------------------------
*/
```

Here is the call from the _header-search.scss file

```
@include bp(min-width, $bp-medium + 1) {

    .skip-search {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of the `sass` plugin as you using? You can run `npm list --depth=0` to check. I was able to fix this error in my build by updating to the latest package, but I'm using `gulp-sass`.

Comment: gulp@3.9.1, gulp-sass@3.0.0, gulp-util@3.0.8, node-delete@0.1.2  --  Do you think 3.0.0 needs to be updated?

Comment: Version 3.1.0 of `gulp-sass` fixed it for me.

Comment: @Mike, will check.

Comment: @MikeWheaton This works,  Can you post as the answer and I will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this error is caused by an outdate version of the `sass-gulp` package. If anyone else is having this issue, try updating to version 3.1.0 or newer.

Comment: sass-gulp or sass-gulp ?